# Nexmo Forward Message to my number

Tags: php, vonage

I have a virtual number in nexmo 447775*****, then my goal is If someone texted me on that number the message will be forwarded to my personal number 55699*****. I read the documentation on how webhook works but I didn't quite sure if that is what I'm looking for. I already search google for a day to search for a tutorial but I didn't find any. Can someone provide me some reference or provide an example? Btw I'm using php.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup your Nexmo virtual to "forward" to your personal number however you need to code your backed as such. Nexmo provides an API to facilitate sending/receiving SMS but it's not a forwarding service. Google Voice would be what you are looking if you want something out of the box. A [Webhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook) is basically a URL that Nexmo would call when you receive an incoming SMS message. Your API/service would receive the message, parse it and do something with it. Hope this helps.